# can't launch application on android L emulator

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

i just installed android L sdk platform and created an emulator then i created a project with minSdkVersion of "L" but eclipse wont let me launch that on emulator it keeps telling me:

```
 ERROR: Application requires a device running 'L'!
 Launch canceled!
```

here is androidmanifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.exmaple"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="L"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

did u made a AVD running android L? 
If not create AVD running android L.